# Dynamically create controls in android using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Using java, to create a control dynamically we use something like
`TextView textview=new TextView(getApplicationContext());`

how can the same be done in Kotlin? `var textview = TextView` 
does't work, nor does `var textview as TextView`

unfortunately, haven't even encountered any good kotlin tutorials for android.

update-Actually am trying to create dynamic listview with a custom layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, by calling the constructor of `TextView`, like so:

```
var textview = TextView(this) // "this" being the Activity
```

See [creating instances](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#creating-instances-of-classes) in the official documentation.

Comment: that's helpful, trying to create an adapter for listview like `var listadapter=ListAdapter(this)` doesn't work though.

Comment: The Kotlin syntax is good, that would call the constructor. However, ListAdapter is an *interface* so it has no constructor and cannot be instantiated. You can only create a concrete subclass that implements ListAdapter. Tip: Make an adapter class that extends BaseAdapter (which implements ListAdapter). Though, this has nothing to do with Kotlin, it is just the regular (java) Android sdk.

Comment: I am very well versed with android java.. its kotlin syntax that i am experimenting with. Btw thanks for the official document​ation link. :)

Answer (score 0):

To create a textview dynamically, you have to call the constructor of textview and store it in a variable like this:

```
var myTextview = TextView(this);
```

You have to write this code in an activity or a fragment because `this` will represent an activity or a fragment.

Then use textview's all the methods like: setText();

```
myTextview.setText("Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 
`var myTextView: TextView? = TextView(this)`
To assign text to TextView
`myTextView?.setText("Hello")`

But myTextView variable cannot be null.