# Android Kotlin Add Checkbox onclicklisener

Tags: android, kotlin

How do I add a `checkBox` element the moment I tick an existing `checkBox` e.g with the id `check1` ?

```
 check1.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { 
?? })
```

Comment: You could take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44138142/dynamically-create-controls-in-android-using-kotlin

Just to help you being helped: you shall denote efforts you made trying to solve your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically create controls in android using Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44138142/dynamically-create-controls-in-android-using-kotlin)

Answer (score 0):

in kotlin do like this-

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Single checked box
        cb_single.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            if (cb_single.isChecked) {
                message(cb_single.text.toString() + " Checked")
            } else {
                message(cb_single.text.toString() + " UnChecked")
            }
        })
    }
```